# Extract unique distinict values based on date range and another criteria without 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

in column `A2:A17` I have numbers list. `column B2:B17` date list. `Column C` contains sections `C2:C17`.

I want generate unique values belongs to by entering start date to `G2` End date to `G3` and section to `G4`. I try below formula works but its get `0` value between generated unique value list if some cells in `column A` is blank.I need unique values without g[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0ndd.png)etting `0` between unique list. some values in column `A:A` is blank.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$17,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1,IF(($G$3>=$B$2:$B$17)*($G$2<=$B$2:$B$17)*($G$4=$C$2:$C$17),$A$2:$A$17,$D$1)),0)),"")
```

Comment: Can you show an example of your data and expected result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$17,MATCH(1,INDEX(($B$2:$B$17>=$G$2)*($B$2:$B$17<=$G$3)*($C$2:$C$17=$G$4)*(COUNTIF(D$1:D1,$A$2:$A$17)=0)*($A$2:$A$17<>""),),0)),"")
```